# how to add Videos in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, video, tablerow

I am developing an app in which I have to show video list in a table view. I want to show different videos in each Row as like youtube shows. I have added mediaplayerFramework only. Please tell me what I have to do next? Can anyone tell me in detail.?

This is my .h file

```
@interface videoViewController :UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
  {

     NSMutableArray * arrImages;

  }
```

and this is my .m file

```
@interface videoViewController ()

@end

@implementation videoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

UITableView *videoTable= [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, Screen_width, Screen_height)];
videoTable.dataSource=self;
videoTable.delegate=self;
arrImages=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"video1",@"video2",@"video3",@"video4",@"video5",@"video6",@"video7", nil];
[self.view addSubview:videoTable];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;

 }
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

 return [arrImages count];

 }

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"CellID";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   if (cell==nil) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


 }
   return cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  return 100;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** *This is one way of adding video in cell*

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

          static NSString *cellIdentifier =@"CellID";
          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
           if (cell==nil) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
              }


             NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURL];
                        moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
                        [moviePlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
                        moviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
                        [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 150.0 , 100.0)];
                        [cell.contentView addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
                         moviePlayer.view.hidden = NO;
                        [moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
                        [moviePlayer play];
    return cell;
}
```

**2.** *But the best way of adding video in cell is to subclass a UITableViewCell and add a MPMoviePlayerController as its Property*

```
@implementation CustomVideoCell
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
        self.movie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.movie.view];
    }
    return self;
 }
 - (void)layoutSubviews {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     self.movie.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, self.bounds.size.width - 80, self.bounds.size.height);
 }
```

In swift 4:

```
        static let tableViewCellIdentifier = "CellID"

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tableViewCellIdentifier)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: tableViewCellIdentifier)
    }


    let videoURL = URL(string: videoURL ?? "")
    if let videoURL = videoURL {
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: videoURL)
    }
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = .none
    moviePlayer.scalingMode = .aspectFit
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 0.0, width: 150.0, height: 100.0)
    cell?.contentView.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
    moviePlayer.view.hidden = false
    moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
    moviePlayer.play()
    return cell!
}
```

......

```
    class CustomVideoCell {
    init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        movie = MPMoviePlayerController()
        movie.scalingMode = .aspectFit
        contentView.addSubview(movie.view)

    }

    func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        movie.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: bounds.size.width - 80, height: bounds.size.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURL];

 Is it right??

Comment: mpmovieplayercontroller is deprecated as of iOS 9

Comment: @joey- Don't expect somebody will find a solution for you ? Why don't you study a bit and add another answer to this question so that it will helpful for SO members.